# Validation in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have following `ng-repeat`. I am iterating `textboxes` & want different name for each `textbox` so i can validate them properly.

The following gives me error. How to unique name `textboxes` in `ng-repeat`?

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="practiceAdd in practice.practiceaddress">
   <td style="width: 10%;">Address  {{$index+1}}</td>
   <td style="width: 30%;">
       <input type="text" name="street{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" data-ng-model="practiceAdd.street{{$index+1}}" ng-class="{'has-error': editForm.street{{$index+1}}.$invalid}" required />
       <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="editForm.street{{$index+1}}.$dirty && editForm.street{{$index+1}}.$invalid">Street name is required</span>
   </td>
   ....
```

Comment: believe the ng-model is your problem not the name attribute

Comment: @shaunhusain Runs now...But validation doesn't show up??

Comment: Recommend moving you're code from ng show and others with logic into functions on the controller

Comment: I think this blog might help address this issue: http://www.thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/08/angularjs-html-form-design-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="practiceAdd in practice.practiceaddress">
   <td style="width: 10%;">Address  {{$index+1}}</td>
   <td style="width: 30%;">
       <input type="text" name="street{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" data-ng-model="practiceAdd.street" required />

   </td>
```